# ember passing new model data into component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I am trying to grasp the way ember works (probably the exact opposite of the way I think).

I am working with ember 2.0.

The test app I am trying to make will show an inventory component on the application index page.  I want to avoid navigating the user through routes (page urls, in this case), and simply give them information on a single page.

If I only want to get the inventory data AFTER the user opens, for instance, a modal dialog, how do I open a component modal and pass in new data?

I recognize that you can pass data into a component like `{{modal-component name=name age=age}}`, but if the data wasn't, how do you get new data after a click?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give as an example of what you trying to do? By the way, you can completely hide routes from browser's address bar by setting App.Router.location to 'none'.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what's being asked here. Do you mean issuing a server request after a user clicks a modal?

Comment: what I am trying to understand is how the model data is 'selected' when you display a component.  As highly touted as embers 'convention over configuration' is, they hardly touch on convention at all in their docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if u had for instance a modal component u could do data fetching when the modal opens. By having modelName as a property you can use the same component where ever you need it.

```
{{modal-component modelName='directory/my-model'}}
```

And in the

*components/modal-components.js*

```
 init: function() {
      this._super();
      this.set('someModalContainer', this.get('store').findAll(this.get('modelName'))
 }
```

Now this code is ran when component is opened, which allows you to fetch data when the neccessary state to open component is completed. Not on the initial load of route or anything.

*components/modal-components.hbs*

```
{{#each someModalContainer as |modalDataItem|}}
     {{modalDataItem.kickassProperty}}
 {{/each}}
```

Comment: Thanks again! You're very helpful.

Comment: @RickyMason Nps! Glad I can help. =3

Comment: @RickyMason You can however pass data from model as well, for simplicity. If you load the page and have like 3 requests(not too much, right?) you might as well make these server queries in route,s function -model. {{modal-component name=model.person.name age=model.person.age}}